# I am trying to Select data from two different tables in one query

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have the following database structure:

Users table:

```
User_id || name    || surname   || email           || marker_id
 1      ||    test ||    tester ||  test@gmail.com ||  1
```

marker table:

```
marker_id || marker_name
1         || testing
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
name ||Surname || email          || marker_name
test || tester || test@gmail.com || testing
```

I am trying to Select all from users table and display instead of marker_id the marker_name.

I also tried to use joins by performing the following query:

```
SELECT m.marker_name FROM marker m JOIN user u ON u.marker_id = m.marker_id
```

**But the output of this query was only the attribute marker_name.**

Comment: select u.*, m.* from user u join marker m on ...

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only select the m.marker_name so you only get this one column, use the query below instead:

```
SELECT u.name, u.surname, u.email, m.marker_name 
FROM marker m 
    JOIN user u ON u.marker_id = m.marker_id
```